# Dataframe: descending sorting not working

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

CityVsPrice=data.frame(City,Price)

```
City      Price

New York  10000
New York  15000
New York  12000
Madison   800
Lodi      8000
Chico     9000
Redlands  200
```

I then wish to sort this list by price, giving me the top 3 cities for price.  So ideally, New York would only show up once, followed by Chico, and then Lodi.  Maybe another way to approach this is take the highest value for each city, and then sort descending and pick top 3.  Any easy way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse does this very well, you will love it :)

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(City,Price) %>% 
  group_by(City) %>% 
  top_n(1, Price) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  top_n(3, Price)
```

Comment: no it doesn't. there might be naming confusion. eg. City is a data.frame and a column name at the same time. this can solve that CityVsPrice <- data.frame(City,Price) ; rm(City, Price)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this in base R concisely but here goes a solution that uses `data.table`:

```
setDT(CityVsPrice)[, .(Price = max(Price)), by=City][order(-Price)][1:3]
       City Price
1: New York 15000
2:    Chico  9000
3:     Lodi  8000
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this finally worked:

```
Price=as.numeric(as.character(Price))

ByPrice<- data.frame(aggregate(Price ~ City, data = CityVsPrice, max))
```